# How to match substring of a string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I don't have much knowledge of regex, so please if you can help me, how to match this string:

> a href="mailto:bristovski@moznosti.com.mk",

which is substring of other string.

Thanks.

Comment: please refer [ho to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What are you trying to find, the href, or an href with a mailto tag?  Or the actual e-mail address?

Comment: i want to find "a href mailTo: any email".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression to validate an email address, you can use the System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class. To determine whether an email address is valid, pass the email address to the MailAddress.MailAddress(String) class constructor.

```
public bool IsValid(string emailaddress)
{
    try
    {
        MailAddress m = new MailAddress(emailaddress);

        return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or

```
string email = txtemail.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
Match match = regex.Match(emailaddress);
if (match.Success)
    Response.Write(emailaddress + " is correct");
else
    Response.Write(email + " is incorrect");
```